# android listview item background image

Tags: android, listview

I want to change the background of a single item from a list. My code changes the background to all items. can you help, please? here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
    android:background="@drawable/friend_bubble"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_message_date"
    >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java code is:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        RelativeLayout rlBubble = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_message_text).getParent();
        Drawable backgroundImage = rlBubble.getBackground();
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (backgroundImage == friendBubble ) {
                rlBubble.setBackgroundDrawable(friendBubbleSelected);
            } else {
                rlBubble.setBackgroundDrawable(userBubbleSelected);
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (backgroundImage == friendBubbleSelected) {
                rlBubble.setBackgroundDrawable(friendBubble);
            } else {
                rlBubble.setBackgroundDrawable(userBubble);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can't see a listview in your code.

Comment: it's a simple list containing a text and a background image.... I don't see list creation code so relevant in this issue...

Comment: it depends on the list style @gabi so yeah the list creation code might be the problem

Comment: i asked that because, you can do, what you want to, by creating your own adapter class and overriding the getView method inside it.

Comment: I've fixed it by removing relative's layout background image and setting it to textview and at background I've used a selector. but thanks anyway